# Vector bundles on blowups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, blow-ups, projective-varieties

$\DeclareMathOperator\Pic{Pic}\DeclareMathOperator\ker{ker}$Let $X$ be a (projective) variety, which is singular at a point $p$ of $X$ (we can also replace $p$ with some closed subvariety). Suppose $Y$ is the blowup of $X$ at $p$ (so $Y$ is a smooth variety). How do vector bundles on $Y$ relate the vector bundles on $X$?

More precisely: let $\pi: Y \to X$ denote the projection. Let $E \to Y$ be a vector bundle on $Y$. I conjecture that there is a vector bundle $F \to X$ such that $E$ is a direct sum of $\pi^*(F)$ and a bunch of line bundles on $Y$.

Note that if $E$ has dimension $1$, then this is true: we have $\Pic(Y) = \Pic(X) (+) Z$. To see this, let $U = X-{p}$, and let $i: U \to Y$ denote the inclusion. Note that $\Pic(U) = \Pic(X)$. The composite $U \to Y \to X$ gives a splitting $\Pic(Y) = \Pic(X) (+) \ker(i^*)$. One can now show that $\ker(i^*) = Z$.

What about blowups along more general subvarieties? For instance, what we blow up along a $P^1$? In this case, the same argument as above goes through: if $Z$ is a closed subvariety of $X$ and $p: Y \to E$ is the blowup of $X$ along $Z$, then $\Pic(Y) = \Pic(X) (+) Z[O_Y(E)]$, where $E = p^{-1}(Z)$ is the exceptional divisor.

Comment: Consider the tangent bundle on $Y$.

Comment: Even more simply, let $X$ be the projective cone over the $d$-fold Veronese embedding of $\mathbb{P}^n$ for $d,n\geq 2$.  The blowing up $Y$ admits a projection to $\mathbb{P}^n$.  Thus, any vector bundle on $\mathbb{P}^n$ that does not split as a direct sum of line bundles pulls back to a counterexample (e.g., the pullback of the tangent bundle on $\mathbb{P}^n$ gives a counterexample).